# How to save the print output into a Excel Table

Tags: python, excel

I have a script that Analyze Tag from a PLC 
and read a bunch of tags A LOT OF THEM 
and i would like to know how can I save the print output into a excel file but with table format

this is part of the script

```
with PLC() as comm:
    comm.IPAddress = '192.168.100.5'
    comm.ProcessorSlot = 0
    ret = comm.GetPLCTime()

    print("Fecha y Hora de Registro Revision Fallas", ret.Value)
    time.sleep(1)
    Estacion = "D2M017"

   #ACTUADOR 1 
   ACTUADOR = comm.Read('D2M_017.Status.Act._1.WBypassed')
   ret = comm.GetPLCTime()
   Numero_Act_EnBypass = 0
   if ACTUADOR.Value == True:
        Sensor = "ACTUADOR 1 WORK SENSOR EN BY PASS"
        Numero_Act_EnBypass = (Numero_Act_EnBypass +1)
       print(Estacion, ret.Value, "D2M017 =",Sensor)
   else:
        Sensor = "ACTUADOR 1 WORK OK"



   ACTUADOR = comm.Read('D2M_017.Status.Act._1.HBypassed')
   ret = comm.GetPLCTime()
   if ACTUADOR.Value == True:
        Sensor = "ACTUADOR 1 HOME SENSOR EN BY PASS"
        Numero_Act_EnBypass = (Numero_Act_EnBypass +1)
        print(Estacion, ret.Value, "D2M017 =",Sensor)
   else:
        Sensor = "ACTUADOR 1 HOME OK"
```

this part is repeated 64 more times
and at the end i have this result

[Result of Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlgRw.png)

and I need to save that info into a Table in excel
splited in parts
Estacion, Date, Status

Comment: Not sure about excel proper, but wouldn't saving into a .csv do the trick? Excel can easily load .csv files. You can EASILY do a csv output in python, a quick search will show you how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at Pandas? Its got a lot of powerful stuff for tables, including direct export to excel. See my simple code below, hope that's useful.

```
import pandas as pd
plc_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Tag', 'DateTime', 'Actuator', 'Value'], dtype=object)
# Code to get tags e.g.:
for i in range(10):
    # This is just a loop to generate data. In your case put your code to extract data correctly
    plc_tag = 'XXX_{0}'.format(i)
    date_time = '2019-06-{0}'.format(i+5)
    actuator = 'ACTUADOR {0}'.format(i)
    act_value = 'Work Ok'
    temp_dict = {'Tag': plc_tag, 'DateTime': date_time, 'Actuator': actuator, 'Value': act_value}
    plc_data = plc_data.append(temp_dict.copy(), ignore_index=True)     # I have used a copy of the dictionary, although I'm not sure it's fully necessary. 

plc_data.to_excel("output.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet_name_1', index=False)
```

Comment: Works perfect
but how can I avoid to overwrite the data? I add 'a' to the line but it display an error   `plc_data.to_excel("output.xlsx", 'a' , sheet_name='Sheet_name_1', index=False)`

Comment: I'm assuming you want to add more lines to that file? There may be better options depending on your situation and goal. But you could simply replace the line which creates the dataframe `plc_data = pd.DataFrame(columns...)` with `plc_data = pd.read_excel("output.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet_name_1')`. This will create the dataframe from existing data. You then append new data to the bottom of the dataframe. When done, save to excel again. It will overwrite the old file with the new data. You could do this a bit more safely by using a new file name etc - that's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to handle that: the simplest is to use a csv writer, and write out to the file instead of, or as well as printing to the console.

Using your code as the base: That could look something like this.

```
import csv

with PLC() as comm:
    with open("output_file.csv",'w') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
...   
#ACTUADOR 1 
   ACTUADOR = comm.Read('D2M_017.Status.Act._1.WBypassed')
   ret = comm.GetPLCTime()
   Numero_Act_EnBypass = 0
   if ACTUADOR.Value == True:
        Sensor = "ACTUADOR 1 WORK SENSOR EN BY PASS"
        Numero_Act_EnBypass = (Numero_Act_EnBypass +1)
        print(Estacion, ret.Value, "D2M017 =",Sensor)
   else:
        Sensor = "ACTUADOR 1 WORK OK"
   csv_writer.writerow([Estacion, ret.Value,f"D2M017 = {Sensor}"])
   ...
```

Etc. If you absolutely need to write out to an excel (.xsl or .xslx) file, there are several packages available: xslxwriter perhaps being one of the easiest to use. https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/

Finally: If you want to save the output of any terminal command to a file you can 'pipe' it out.

In windows and linux, that would look like: python_script.py > myoutputfile.txt